# Log errors in Elmah for Azure functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

This how I enabled error logging in Webjobs:

```
public static class ElmahExtension
    {
        public static void LogToElmah(this Exception ex)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            }
            else
            {
                if (httpApplication == null) InitNoContext();
                ErrorSignal.Get(httpApplication).Raise(ex);
            }
        }

        private static HttpApplication httpApplication = null;
        private static ErrorFilterConsole errorFilter = new ErrorFilterConsole();

        public static ErrorMailModule ErrorEmail = new ErrorMailModule();
        public static ErrorLogModule ErrorLog = new ErrorLogModule();
        public static ErrorTweetModule ErrorTweet = new ErrorTweetModule();

        private static void InitNoContext()
        {
            httpApplication = new HttpApplication();
            errorFilter.Init(httpApplication);

            (ErrorEmail as IHttpModule).Init(httpApplication);
            errorFilter.HookFiltering(ErrorEmail);

            (ErrorLog as IHttpModule).Init(httpApplication);
            errorFilter.HookFiltering(ErrorLog);

            (ErrorTweet as IHttpModule).Init(httpApplication);
            errorFilter.HookFiltering(ErrorTweet);
        }

        private class ErrorFilterConsole : ErrorFilterModule
        {
            public void HookFiltering(IExceptionFiltering module)
            {
                module.Filtering += new ExceptionFilterEventHandler(base.OnErrorModuleFiltering);
            }
        }
    }
```

How to setup Elmah logging in `Azure functions` app project and also show line number information where the error occurred?

**NOTE:** Azure functions calls functions from separate referenced assembly [service project].

Answer (score 2):

ELMAH isn't built for Azure Functions. To my knowledge, setting up ELMAH logging the normal way in a functions isn't possible. You can configure ELMAH almost from code (experimented with it here: [Configure elmah.io from code](https://docs.elmah.io/configure-elmah-io-from-code/)), but you will need to add code to `web.config`, which isn't available.

One thing you could try, is the [ELMAH bootstrapper](https://github.com/elmah/Bootstrapper). It automatically register ELMAH on startup. I haven't tried it on Functions, but it might be worth a shot.

I also want to quickly mention Microsoft.Extensions.Logger. Functions do in fact support injecting an ILogger, but for now it logs to disk or Application Insights. In the future, this will probably be extended to support thirdparty destinations as well. You should keep an eye on https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1579.